# One session across multiple instances of a class

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I have MyClass class with Session from `requests`

```
import requests

class MyClass(object):
    s = requests.Session()

    def test(self):
        print self.s
```

Then I tested

```
In[3]: a = mymodule.MyClass()
In[4]: b = mymodule.MyClass()
In[5]: print a
<mymodule.MyClass object at 0x10e074c50>
In[6]: print b
<mymodule.MyClass object at 0x10e074d10>
In[7]: a.test()
<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x10dbe5550>
In[8]: b.test()
<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x10dbe5550>
```

how is the session object from a and b are the same one? I would expect to have two different sessions created one for a and the other one for b.

I don't think `Session` is a singleton. As it shows, calling `requests.Sessions()` twice and two different Session instances created. 
So why the session in `a` and `b` are the same?

```
In[13]: s1 = requests.Session()
In[14]: s2 = requests.Session()
In[15]: print s1
<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x10e089210>
In[16]: print s2
<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x10e089650>
```

Comment: Your `s` is a class attribute, so it is stored once, on the class.  Google to find gazillions of questions about the difference between class and instance attributes in Python.

Comment: ugh .. thanks .. new to python :p

Comment: looks like Java syntax, but it isn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` is a class attribute in your case - it would be initialized once and shared across all class instances. Make the session an *instance variable* instead:

```
import requests

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.Session()

    def test(self):
        print self.s
```